# NaN on addition

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a score update on the push of a button. I'm getting the value `NaN` when I run the function. I thought adding Number() into my function around the individual scores would fix it but it hasn't. Any ideas?

```js
function SCOREUPDATE() {
    var A = document.getElementById("SCORE1A").value;
    var B = document.getElementById("SCORE1B").value;
    var z = Number(A) + Number(B);
    document.getElementById("TOTALSCORE").innerHTML = z;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Enter" onClick="SCOREUPDATE();">
<p id="SCORE1A">1</p>
<p id="SCORE1B">2</p>

<p id="TOTALSCORE"></p>
```

Comment: `console.log("A: ", A);`

Comment: Using the jQuery library can reduce some of the amount of code you need to write to do things like this. Some would argue that it's overkill but it really depends on the project: https://jquery.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p` element does not have property `value`, you can access content of tag with `innerHTML` (or better `.textContent` as mentioned in comments):

```
var A = document.getElementById("SCORE1A").textContent;
```

Comment: Make sure to use ``parseInt`` or ``parseFloat``

Comment: You probably want `.textContent` not `.innerHTML` - you expect a plain numeric string, not html markup.